# Loading image in Android as static server

Tags: go

I'm tryig to run `GO` server in my Android app, the app is running the camera,and saving files at:

```sh
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.myapp/
```

I'm trying to define this bath as the static path in my server, as:

```golang
fsAndroid := http.FileServer(http.Dir("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.myapp/"))
http.Handle("/android/", fsAndroid)

    go func() {
        log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:6060", nil))
        <-c
    }()
```

But once I tried to open the files saved there, after being taken from the camera, and I go to:

```sh
http://127.0.0.1:6060/android/myfile.jpg
```

I'm getting the `404 page not found`

Any thought?

Comment: `file://` indicates a URL, not a local filesystem path. Just use `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.myapp/`.

Comment: @Adrian got same result :(

Comment: And you've confirmed that `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.myapp/android/myfile.jpg` exists and is readable by the user running your Go app?

Comment: @Adrian how to confirm that? The user running the app can save files in that location, and any gallary app can open that location and see all its contents, even grom the browser I can see myfile.jpg, that location should be public for all apps (including the app created it)

Comment: Two things: (1) Hooking up a `http.FileServer` to a subpath with `http.Handle` does not automatically strip that prefix, so a request to `/android/myfile.jpg` would attempt to open `/storage/.../com.myapp/android/myfile.jpg`. See the [StripPrefix example](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer). (2) "Public" storage access on Android is a complicated topic, especially [since Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage).

Comment: @fizze thanks a lot, the 'StripPrefec' solved my issue with Android 10, I'll try updating it now to Android 12 and see the impact on storage access, but at least by your help, I knew in which code the issue was, and aware in which code an issue could appear upon upgrade

Comment: Hi @fizzie, just wanted you to have a look at my answer, if you have any comment, it worked with Android 12. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, and sharing my files: [here](https://github.com/hajsf/go-android-photo)

1. From Go, I used, thanks for [fizzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16606551/fizzie) note above:

```golang
    fsAndroid := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/storage/emulated/0/")) // Pictures/tk.cocoon/

    http.Handle("/android/", http.StripPrefix("/android/", fsAndroid))
```

2. In Android, I used:

```kotlin
interface ImageUri {
    companion object {
        fun create() : Uri? {
            // Create an image file name
            val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            Global.fileName = "IMG_${timeStamp}.jpg"
            Global.filePath = "Pictures/tk.cocoon/IMG_${timeStamp}.jpg"

            val resolver = Global.context.contentResolver
            val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, Global.fileName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                //put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Android/media/tk.cocoon/")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/tk.cocoon/")
            }
            Global.photoURI = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            return Global.photoURI
        }
    }
}
```